# 401 unauthorized ajax call error to Watson Assistant API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make ajax request to Watson Assistant API from client side only, so I had this code in php which is working fine but when I tried to make it in jQuery I got 401 unauthorized error.

**PHP:**

```
$data['input']['text'] = $_POST['message'];
if(isset($_POST['context']) && $_POST['context']){
  $data['context'] = json_decode($_POST['context'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
$data['alternate_intents'] = false;
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

// Post the json to the Watson API via cURL.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/'.$workspace_id.'/message?version='.$release_date);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = trim( curl_exec( $ch ) );
curl_close($ch);

// Responce the result.
echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    message: message,
    context: context
  },
  headers:{
    'Authorization' : 'Basic' + btoa('f7be829c-ae6d-47d8-b2bd-65a40ad45aa' +':'+ 'hJcToxQ23Zk'),
  },
  contentType: 'application/json',
  timeout:10000
})
```

Anything missing from the JS code?

 Note: credentials mentioned are for example only.

Comment: Is the username really _f7be829c-ae6d-47d8-b2bd-65a40ad45aa_ ? That seems like a token of some sort.

Comment: Should it be `'Basic '` ?

Comment: are you try remove btoa ?